# replicate both screenspace and world space valley in eevee material?

Tags: materials, ambient-occlusion, workbench-render-engine

in the "workbench" rendering engine of blender there is an option called "cavity" where you can enable a feature which is called "valley" which basically is similar to ambient occlusion where it fills tight spaces with darkness in the model. is there any way to create a similar effect in an eevee material? i know world space is pretty much just the ambient occlusion node, but i am unsure of how to replicate screen space. and i would like to have both enabled at the same time. is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Eevee has capability to get there, since all edge detection nodes (like Bevel, Pointiness, or what ever) is not working in Eevee.

---

The closest I was able to get is with **Cycles** and yet with problematic part.
Node tree contains *Pointiness* feature that is sensitive for vertex distances, so to get there I had to use Subdivision Modifier in a very high level. So whole this example is quite useless.

So just for an idea or someones exploration ...

Workbench
[image]

Cycles
[image]

[image]

[image]